# all requests coming to cloudfoundry return 403 bad request

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, java-cfenv

I have moved from `spring-cloud-connector` to `java-cfenv` library with all the corresponding  changes.

When testing locally - running with setting (VCAP_SERVICES) environment variable and `-Dspring.profiles.active=cloud` I am able to connect (to remote services like RDS or vault) and run the application just fine.

However when I deploy it to cloudfoundry - each request returns 403 Bad Request.
The manifest for the application looks like this

```
applications:
- buildpacks:
  - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v4.38
  disk_quota: 1GB
  env:
    JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{ enabled: false }'
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
  instances: 4
  memory: 2GB
  name: app-blue
  path: ./app.jar
  routes:
  - route: app-blue.us-east.domain.com
  - route: app-blue.com
  - route: app.com
  services:
  - log_drain
  - hc_vault
  - db_service
  stack: cflinuxfs3
```

In CFlogs, it also shows that that the active profile `cloud` too, just like locally.
What might be the problem?

Comment: It's not clear why changing SCC to java-cfenv would result in a 403. A 403 means you have an authorization problem. Does your application require an authorized user? If so, how is that being enforced? Are you using Spring Security? Is some part of your Spring Security configuration using a bound service?

Comment: But that's the thing. I haven't changed anything else - not even in properties. And that's why I am able to run it locally (with VCAP set and profiles cloud set). I can trigger 403 if I for example do requests requiring HTTPS while HTTP (we have such check that trigger 403), but all CF requests are HTTPS

Comment: You have to get past the "nothing changed" mentality. Obviously, something isn't working or you'd not be getting 403s. What you're talking about seems like a good place to start. It could be that the HTTPS information is not being properly passed through to your application. When your app runs on CF, TLS termination happens before the application at load balancers, so that information is passed through the `x-forwarded-*` headers. Spring Boot will handle these headers, but you should check to confirm they are being set by your LB and that you do not need to adjust the Boot configuration.

Comment: See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/securing-traffic.html#http_header_gorouter and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server for Boot.